# Creating a line graph of numbers from a .txt file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I have a text file containing a series of numerical values. Lets say the .txt file is called numbers.txt and it contains the values (283, 927, 273, 284, 251). How do I use python to create a line graph of these values?

The x-axis tells us what position the number is in within the series. For instance, 927 is 2nd so x=2. In other words the coordinates would be (1, 283), (2, 927) etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The file `numbers.txt` contains:

```
283, 927, 273, 284, 251
```

With numpy and matplotlib:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt("/path/to/your/numbers.txt", delimiter=",")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(len(data)), data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install matplotlib with `python -m pip install matplotlib`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get data from our file
with open('my_file_name.txt', 'r') as f:
   text = f.read() 

# This part really depends on how your txt data is formatted
text = text.replace(")", "")
text = text.replace("(", "")
text = text.replace(" ", "")
text_list = text.split(",")

# Turn our list of strings into a list of numbers
y_values = [float(i) for i in text_list]

# Get a list of x-values to correspond with our y-values
count = len(number_list)
x_values = [i for i in range(1, count + 1)]

# Plot it
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.show()
```

Let me know if you have any specific questions.  I know a lot of the syntax may be foreign if you're new to Python.  I also didn't test the script, so comment if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file called `numbers.txt` with the following contents:

```
283, 927, 273, 284, 251
```

You could use [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), (seaborn is a superset of `matplotlib`) to create your line graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


def main() -> None:
    data = {'x': [], 'y': []}
    with open('numbers.txt') as data_file:
        for x, y in enumerate(data_file.readlines()[0].split(', '), start=1):
            data['x'].append(x)
            data['y'].append(int(y))
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    sns.lineplot(data=data, x='x', y='y')
    plt.xticks(ticks=data['x'])
    plt.title('graph')
    plt.savefig('graph.svg')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output Graph:**

[image: Graph]